# install autocomplete-plus package in windows

Tags: atom-editor

im trying to install the autocomplete-plus plugin for Atom Editor in Windows but when I do I get an error saying:
( I have git & chocolatey intalled )
....Other packages like minimap same problem blablaaa blaaaaaaa
with themes apm install [theme ] no problems to install

```
C:\Windows\system32>apm install autocomplete-plus
Installing autocomplete-plus to C:\Users\*\.atom\packages failed

npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/emissary
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore-plus
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/temp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fuzzaldrin
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore-plus
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fuzzaldrin
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/emissary
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/semver
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/temp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mixto
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/property-accessors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm ERR! git fetch -a origin (https://github.com/Benvie/harmony-collections.git)
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
npm ERR! Error: Command failed: fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
npm ERR!
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
npm ERR!     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
npm ERR!     at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
npm ERR!     at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:969:11)
npm ERR!     at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
npm ERR!     at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\Atom.0.150.0\\tools\\Atom\\r
esources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\atom-package-manager\\bin\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Pr
ogramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\Atom.0.150.0\\tools\\Atom\\resources\\app\\apm\\node
_modules\\atom-package-manager\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--globalcon
fig" "C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\Atom.0.150.0\\tools\\Atom\\resources\\ap
p\\apm\\node_modules\\atom-package-manager\\.apmrc" "--userconfig" "C:\\Users\\l
gaona\\.atom\\.apmrc" "install" "C:\\Users\\*\\.atom\\.node-gyp\\.atom\\.ap
m\\autocomplete-plus\\0.22.3\\package.tgz" "--target=0.18.0" "--arch=ia32"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\*\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-1141027-4616-1si
7t3x
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.33
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.4
npm ERR! code 128
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mixto
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/property-accessors
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf 
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lru-cache
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sigmund
npm
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The same error is described in relation to Atom in the following places:

- https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5346
- https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2206

It looks like people solved this through the following steps:

- Verify that the *git* command is on the PATH.
- Use PowerShell to run the command instead of *cmd* or *git-bash*.
- Run PowerShell in administrator mode.

Can you try to see if they help in your case?