# Git returns fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'

Tags: git, github, https, html

I'm trying to link the contents of my .me webpage to my <>.github.io webpage. When I open the terminal and enter...

```
git clone https://github.com/<<username>>/<<username>>.github.io
```

It returns...

```
/<<username>>/<<username>>.github.io
Cloning into '<<username>>.github.io'...
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'https'
```

I've tried a bunch of solutions posted under similar problems, but to be honest, I'm not sure what the remote helper is, or how to download/configure one.

Any help is appreciated, and I apologize if I missed something, or didn't format something correctly.

Comment: I thought so too, but I have no luck when I mimic the same solution! I posted in case there was some minute detail holding me back.

Comment: I've answered a similar question here recently: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27178363/install-autocomplete-plus-package-in-windows